# Mapping & fetching entities with composite keys using spring data JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring MVC and Data JPA. I am trying to do mapping tables I have. The structure is like below:

```
Device
--------------
PK deviceId
   deviceName


Setting
--------------
PK deviceId
PK packageName
PK name
   value
```

And I have classes for those tables:

```
@Entity
public class DeviceSetting implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private String deviceId
    private String deviceName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="deviceId", referencedColumnName="deviceId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Device device;

    //Setters and Getters
}

@Embeddable
public class DeviceSettingPk implements Serializable {

    private String deviceId;
    private String packageName;
    private String name;

    public DeviceSettingPk(){}
    public DeviceSettingPk(String deviceId, String packageName, String name) {
        super();
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.name = name;
    }

       //Setters and Getters
}

@Entity
public class Device implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotEmpty
    @Id
    @Column(name="deviceId")
    private String deviceId;

        private String deviceName;

        //Getters and Setters
}
```

But I did not get device data when I put device and setting data has same deviceId and queried DeviceSetting by using repository.findOne(deviceId);

What else do I need to do to get the device data? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the mapping as follows.

```
@Entity
public class DeviceSetting implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private DeviceSettingPk deviceSettingId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="deviceId", referencedColumnName="deviceId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Device device;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

And then use the following code to lookup.

```
DeviceSettingPk id = new DeviceSettingPk(deviceId, packageName, name);

// use the deviceSettingRespository to lookup
repository.findOne(id);
```